# Recursive XSLT transformation with attributes

Tags: c#, xslt

With the following XML :

```
<Sections><Section Type="Type1" Text="blabla1"><Section Type="Type2" Text="blabla2"/>  </Section></Sections>
```

I want to produce the following output :

```
<Sections><Type1 Text="blabla1"><Type2 Text="blabla2"/></Type1></Sections>
```

I'm playing with XSLT since many hours, I cant even figure out something to start with... There are many good example on XLST transformation but I'm still missing something about recursivity and using the Type attribute to create my node.  How to transform any section node in the document to its corresponing type attribute?

Any tutorial that do something similar , xslt resources or anything to start with whould be great

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How's this (as requested in comments, modified to convert in both directions):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Prevent Type attributes from being copied to the output-->
  <xsl:template match="@Type" />

  <!-- Convert <Section Type="Nnn" ... /> into <Nnn ... /> -->
  <xsl:template match="Section">
    <xsl:element name="{@Type}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Convert <Nnn .... /> into <Section Type="Nnn" ... /> -->
  <xsl:template match="Sections//*[not(self::Section)]">
    <Section Type="{name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </Section>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output when run on your first example:

```
<Sections>
  <Type1 Text="blabla1">
    <Type2 Text="blabla2" />
  </Type1>
</Sections>
```

Output when run on your second example:

```
<Sections>
  <Section Type="Type1" Text="blabla1">
    <Section Type="Type2" Text="blabla2" />
  </Section>
</Sections>
```

Comment: Exactly what I need... My god I really need to learn more about XSLT :(   Thanks JLRishe!

Comment: and if I want to do an xslt that put back the xml to it's original value ? (the oposite process)  sorry for asking again

Comment: Updated the example above.  Though if it gets more involved than that you may want to split it out into different transforms for converting in each direction (the "revert to original" transform only requires the 1st and 4th `xsl:template` in that transform).

Comment: Thanks again JLRishe...  XSLT is so powerfull, will defenitively try to spent more time on learning this and play a bit with your example.  :)